# I need to ignore empty strings from an Azure Function written in C#

Tags: c#, azure, function

I have managed to ignore the null buts but I have not been able to do the same with the empty strings. My project is an Azure Function running on .NET Core 3.1.

The configuration I have is the following in the startup

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


builder.Services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(option =>
            {
                option.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                option.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
                option.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true;
            });
```

Any idea why I don't ignore empty strings?

Comment: What is your goal re ignoring empty strings? On serialization, or deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings seems to be correct.
However you might need to decorate your properties with the Default value attribute for [DefaultValueHandling.Ignore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_defaultvaluehandling.htm) to kick in

Below is a working sample

```
static void Main()
{
    var planet = new Planet();

    planet.planetName = "";

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

    settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(planet, settings));

}
    
public class Planet
{
    public string planetID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string planetName { get; set; }

}
```

Output : planetName property is ignored while serializing
[image]

EDIT :

Tried to implement AZ function app with a startup file and added settings for serialization. But I found that ***adding newtonsoft serializer settings to builder services has no effect on serialization***.

Best workaround would be to add settings to function while serializing like below example from AZ function that i tried out.

```
 FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

        settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        Planet deserializedPlanet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Planet>(content);

        string stringified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedPlanet,settings);

        string responseMessage = $"JSON serialized output{stringified}";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
```

Input :
[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: I made your suggestion and it doesn't work for me.
`
                {
                    "PropertyId": "500",
                    "PropertyName": "Número de documento",
                    "PropertyValue": "",
                    "PropertyTypeListValue": "",
                    "PropertyRequired": "true",
                    "IsAssistanceType": "false"
                }
`

Comment: Can you please add your model class to the question as well ?

Comment: @JhotaMSDeveloper please check the edit and see if it may help

Comment: I have put the model in comments

Answer (score 0):

Maybe override the tostring method and pass in your JSON options there or just do some isnullorempty checks before you jsonStringify.
or use

```
[JsonProperty("{propertyname}",DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

```
static void Main()
{
    var planet = new Planet();

    planet.planetName = "";

    Console.WriteLine(planet.ToString());

}

public class Planet
{
    public string planetID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    // optionally use this if you want fine grain controll
    //[JsonProperty("planetName",DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string planetName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this,
                                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                                        {
                                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                                            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
                                        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The model that I am waiting for is the following

```
{
"product": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "room_premium",
    "city": "medellin"
},
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "PolicyHolder",
        "inputParameterId": 495,
        "inputParameterType": "Object",
        "inputParameterSchemaList": [
            {
                "propertyId": "562",
                "propertyName": "Birthdate",
                "propertyValue": "",
                "propertyTypeDescription": "Text",
                "propertyTypeListValue": ""
            },
            {
                "propertyId": "566",
                "propertyName": "IdentificationNumber",
                "propertyValue": "",
                "propertyTypeDescription": "Text",
                "propertyTypeListValue": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

But I should ignore the

```
"propertyValue": "",
"propertyTypeListValue": ""
```